# Make a Negative number Positive - XSLT

Tags: xslt

I was wondering whether there is a way to make a negative value, positive? Here is a snippet of my xslt document:

```
<NumberOfLinesAtRate>
    <xsl:value-of select="number(/xsales:Qty)" />
</NumberOfLinesAtRate>
```

The problem is, sometimes this `Qty` value may be negative, -1, -2 etc.. in my original XML document. Is there a way I can make this always be positive in my transformed document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using XSLT1.0 you can use this formula (I've left out the namespace for brevity)

```
<xsl:value-of select="Qty * (Qty >= 0) - Qty * not(Qty >= 0)" />
```

In XSLT2.0 there is a dedicated **abs** operator you can use

```
<xsl:value-of select="abs(Qty)" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be a fairly concise way to do it:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Qty * (1 - 2 * (Qty < 0))" />
```